# Elixir - get the map from Enum.each()

Tags: elixir

I am new to `Elixir` and trying out [this exercism](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/688b55d942c24754b99ce41d950841a8). Below are my code:

```elixir
  def count(sentence) do
    a = sentence
        |> String.downcase()
    sort_a = Regex.split(~r/([^a-z(\-)]+)/, a)
             |> Enum.sort()
    uniq_a = Enum.uniq(sort_a)
    
    map = Map.new(uniq_a,fn x -> { x, 0 } end)

    final_map = Enum.each(map, fn {k, v} ->
      Map.replace!(map, k, v + match_check(k, sort_a))  
    end)
    final_map
  end

  def match_check(x, [word|words]) do
    if x == word do
      1
    else
      0
    end
    match_check(x, words)
  end

  def match_check(x, []), do: nil
```

At the moment, I am stuck at `Enum.each/2`, which only return `:ok`. thus my `final_map` will get `:ok`. How can I get the result instead?

Comment: What is the question? It's not possible to view it without creating an account.

Comment: Elixir 1.10+: [Enum.frequencies/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1)

Comment: @7stud Elixir seems to have all this useful functions, just that for beginner like me will take sometime to find out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to view your link without creating an account, so I'm not sure what the problem is, but [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) is designed to perform side effects, such as printing the values, so you don't normally care about the return value. For converting the values, you generally want [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2). For example:

```elixir
Enum.each(["hello", "world!"], &IO.puts/1)
```

Returns `:ok` and prints:

```elixir
hello
world!
```

Compared to:

```elixir
Enum.map(["hello", "world!"], &String.capitalize/1)
```

Which doesn't print anything, and returns:

```elixir
["Hello", "World!"]
```

From your example, I'm guessing you are trying to count the number of unique words in a sentence, ignoring case. In that case, a possible solution using [`String.split/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/1), [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3), and [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update/4) is:

```elixir
"a b B CC cc cC"
|> String.split()
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn word, counts ->
  Map.update(counts, String.downcase(word), 1, &(&1 + 1))
end)
```

Output:

```elixir
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "cc" => 3}
```

Comment: @Adamn Milerchip Thanks. your answer is spot on. I guess I still have a lot more to learn.